# text4ht and LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, tex4ht

There is a specific command to run tex4ht with XeTeX: `htxelatex` (which doesn't really work actually as far as I'm concerned).

What is the command to run text4ht with LuaTeX instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit Oct 2015**:

Issues with babel are now fixed, the document can be compiled without errors.

[make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht), new build tool for `tex4ht` supports LuaLaTeX out of the box, you can just use

```
make4ht -l filename
```

The minimal sample file may look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\begin{document}
Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy. Nazd\~ar
\end{document}
```

There is also some experimental support for `Fontspec`, see [my guide](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html)

---

**Original post**

You can try this shell script, windows version is [there](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2011q3/000365.html)

```
#!/bin/sh
lualatex --output-format=dvi --jobname=$1 $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,xhtml]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
lualatex --output-format=dvi --jobname=$1 $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,xhtml]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
lualatex --output-format=dvi --jobname=$1 $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,xhtml]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
tex4ht -.dvi -f/$1  -i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/$3
t4ht -.dvi -f/$1 $4 ## -d~/WWW/temp/ -m644
```

save it as `htlualatex` and make executable.

This code sample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Does it make sense?}
Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy  
\end{document}
```

gives some compilation errors about invalid utf-8 sequences, but the html output is correct. Without `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` the output file ended at the first accented character.

Comment: That seems to work, but I get tons of `LaTeX Error: Command \`\acute' already defined in \`'.` errors like with XeTeX.

Comment: yes, I think there is no correct support for lualatex in tex4ht now, and this is the best what we could get.

Comment: @Raphink: You can't use fontspec + system fonts with tex4ht. tex4ht.exe will be looking for tfm files. You can find some discussion about the problems in the thread starting here: `http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/tex4ht/2011q3/000326.html`

Comment: Which parameters does this shell script expect? from what i've seen 5 but I don't really know which one is which one.. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @MichaelWeibel see http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-33