# Anchor at end of every line

Tags: tex4ht, anchor

Is it possible to fix any `Anchor` or `any indicator` at the end of each an every line of a document? Also note that `Anchor/Indicator` should not be displayed in the output. I am searching for this to check the possibility in F/L (Fixed Layout) in `TeX4ht`, please suggest ...

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Investigate if lineno.sty can attach your anchors (whatever they are) suitably.

Comment: note that you will get different line breaks in TeX4ht than in PDF, as for example word breaking is disabled. What do you want to achieve with these anchors?

Comment: @michal.h21 I'm trying to do match the line endings and page endings both in `TeX output` and `HTML`, as similar as Fixed Layout EPUB...Excuse if this try is stupid....

Comment: ah, yes, this is incredibly hard. I've tried it for years  -- actually, back in 2011: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39690/2891. this version worked only for really simple documents. anyway, here is updated version: https://github.com/michal-h21/realpgno. I always wanted to deal only with page numbers. It works with LuaTeX, in the master run it saves pages as text and corresponding page numbers. When I try to insert page numbers in other compilation, it loads this saved text and inserts marks on places where the page had been broken in the master document. It still doesn't work :/